# roslibjs connection refused

Tags: ros, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, was going through the tutorial for rosibsjs and tried to create my own websocket connection to my robot. However while opening the connection on my chomre browser, I was given a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`error

Does anyone know what may be the cause?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200865/roslibjs-connection-refused/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2015-01-13**:
Can you post a code sample somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey the problem was resolved. The issue was because the websocket was not started on the robot's end. Silly mistake on my part ^^"

---

Originally posted by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) with karma: 93 on 2015-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0